# MySql Workbench permission denied accessing directory

Tags: permissions, ssh, mysql-workbench

I am trying to set Standard TCP/IP over SSH connection but got error when adding ssh key.

> Error opening directory '/home/user/.ssh': Permission denied

How to give permission to MySql Workbench to access the directory and key?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Did you install via snap? If so, snap does not have permissions to the `.ssh` keys by default. It needs permissions to allow Workbench to read my ssh keys:

```
snap connect mysql-workbench-community:ssh-keys
```